# Core Data Fetching

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I've spent many hours searching for an answer for this problem that seems simple.

So these are my parse methods:

```
-(void)ParseJSON {

    NSURL *URL=[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://www.foo24.com/kokos"];
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                    URL];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(JSONtoArrays:)
                           withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
}
-(void)JSONtoArrays:(NSData *)responseData {

    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData:responseData

                          options:kNilOptions
                          error:&error];

    NSMutableArray *fetchCustomersArray=[json objectForKey:@"Customers"];
    NSMutableArray *fetchOrdersArray=[json objectForKey:@"Orders"];

    [self setJSONCustomers:fetchCustomersArray];
    [self setJSONOrders:fetchOrdersArray];

}
```

and this is my fetch from database method:

```
-(void)fetchOrders{


    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

    if (managedObjectContext == nil) 
    { 
        managedObjectContext = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]; 
    }

    NSEntityDescription *orderEntity=[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"OrderEntity" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    NSPredicate *NonDelivered =
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"orderDelivered == NO"];

    //setup fetch request
    NSFetchRequest *request=[[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    [request setEntity:orderEntity];
    [request setPredicate:NonDelivered];


    //fetch
    NSError *error;
    NSMutableArray *FetchResultsArray=[[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error]mutableCopy];

    [self setDbOrders:FetchResultsArray];
    [dbOrders addObjectsFromArray:JSONOrders];
    NSLog(@"%@",[[dbOrders objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"orderName"]);
    [self addOrders:dbOrders];
}
```

What I want to do is to retrieve the non-delivered items from Core Data as an array, then take the new parsed array, delete all entries from database, merge the two arrays and put them back in the database . I don't know if there is as simpler way to do this.

Comment: What do you mean "merge the two arrays". One contains customers, the other orders. Isn't it easier to just delete all delivered orders?

Comment: No there are 2 arrays with orders. The one is the one parsed from the internet and the other is the current in the database.So I need to somehow merged them in order to keep track which orders have been delivered

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know if there is as simpler way to do this,

There is.

Assuming that the array from the internet conains the orders that you want to add to the database, just iterate through these orders and add them to the database.

Simple, right?

Comment: Thanks for answering, however I want to keep track of the delivered orders. For example, when I am synchronizing again i need to know which orders have been delivered so not updating them again :)